# RazorPages AnchorTagHelper does not remove Index from href

Tags: asp.net-core, routes, localization, razor-pages, culture

Recently I started using RazorPages. (3.1)

In my cshtml, when i use:

`<a asp-page="/Index">`

The generated HTML is:

`<a href="/">`

Nice and clean.

The moment I introduce a custom PageRouteModelConvention (for the culture) and a custom AnchorTagHelper, it no longer behaves this way.

As soon as my URL starts with the culture (domain.com/nl-BE/) the link to the the home page looks like this:

`<a href="/nl-BE/Index">`

While i would like to keep it without the Index, as before

`<a href="/nl-BE">`

**Any idea how to fix this?**

The Route convention for adding my culture to the url:

```
    public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            var selectorCount = model.Selectors.Count;

            for (var i = 0; i < selectorCount; i++)
            {
                var selector = model.Selectors[i];

                model.Selectors.Add(new SelectorModel
                {
                    AttributeRouteModel = new AttributeRouteModel
                    {
                        Order = -1,
                        Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template),
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

The default anchortaghelper is replaced by this:

```
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ActionAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ControllerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = AreaAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageHandlerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = FragmentAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = HostAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ProtocolAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesDictionaryName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesPrefix + "*")]
    public class CultureAnchorTagHelper : AnchorTagHelper
    {
        public CultureAnchorTagHelper(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IHtmlGenerator generator) :
            base(generator)
        {
            this._contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        private const string ActionAttributeName = "asp-action";
        private const string ControllerAttributeName = "asp-controller";
        private const string AreaAttributeName = "asp-area";
        private const string PageAttributeName = "asp-page";
        private const string PageHandlerAttributeName = "asp-page-handler";
        private const string FragmentAttributeName = "asp-fragment";
        private const string HostAttributeName = "asp-host";
        private const string ProtocolAttributeName = "asp-protocol";
        private const string RouteAttributeName = "asp-route";
        private const string RouteValuesDictionaryName = "asp-all-route-data";
        private const string RouteValuesPrefix = "asp-route-";
        private const string Href = "href";

        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;
        private readonly string defaultRequestCulture = "en";

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var culture = (string)_contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.RouteValues["culture"];

            if (culture != null && culture != defaultRequestCulture)
            {
                RouteValues["culture"] = culture;
            }

            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Change like below:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc().AddRazorPagesOptions(options =>
    {
        options.Conventions.AddFolderRouteModelConvention("/", model =>
        {
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
            {
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template);
            }
        });
    });
    services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options => {
        var supportedCultures = new CultureInfo[] {
        new CultureInfo("en"),
        new CultureInfo("fr")
        };

        options.DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en");
        options.SupportedCultures = supportedCultures;
        options.SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures;

        options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new RouteDataRequestCultureProvider()
        {
            RouteDataStringKey = "culture",
            UIRouteDataStringKey = "culture",
            Options = options
        });
    });
    services.AddDbContext<Razor3_1Context>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Razor3_1Context")));
}

// This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    if (env.IsDevelopment())
    {
        app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
    }
    else
    {
        app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
        // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
        app.UseHsts();
    }

    var options = app.ApplicationServices.GetService<IOptions<RequestLocalizationOptions>>();
    app.UseRequestLocalization(options.Value);

    app.UseHttpsRedirection();
    app.UseStaticFiles();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
        endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    });
}
```

Result:
[image]