# Using URL path for localization in Razor + Blazor components

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, localization, blazor

I want to build an ASP.NET Razor app with razor pages and some Blazor components, with site content being localized based on the language in the URL.

For example, `/en/home` and `/fr/home` would have one backing page that renders content based on the language.

What's a method to accomplish this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization` [has what we need.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Inside `_ViewImports.cshtml`, we can inject an `IViewLocalizer` which will grab `.resx` files for the corresponding pages.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Localization
@inject IViewLocalizer Localizer
```

Now the `Localizer` is available inside all our pages.

For example, `Index.cshtml`

```
@page
@model IndexModel

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = @Localizer["Title"];
}

<h1>@Localizer["Header"]</h1>
<section>
    <p>@Localizer["Welcome", User.Identity.Name]</p>
    @Localizer["Learn"]
    <a asp-page="Page1">@Localizer["SomePage"]</a>
    <a asp-page="Dogs/Index">@Localizer["LinkDogs"]</a>
</section>
```

Now the page title, header, and content is localized once the resx files are created.

`Resources/Pages/Index.resx` and `Resources/Pages/Index.fr.resx` needs to be created. There is a VSCode extension available for this since these files are just ugly XML.

Strings can be parameterized. In the `Index.cshtml` example, `"Welcome"="Howdy {0}"` gets referenced by `@Localizer["Welcome", User.Identity.Name]` and the username will be substituted in for `{0}`.

Inside `Startup.cs`, we also need to add some setup.

```cs
            services.AddLocalization(options =>
            {
                options.ResourcesPath = "Resources";
            }); // new
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation()
                .AddViewLocalization(); // new
            services.AddServerSideBlazor();
```

But this only gives access to the `Localizer` inside our `.cshtml` files. Our pages still look like `/home` instead of `/en/home`.

To fix this, we will add an `IPageRouteModelConvention` to modify our page templates, prepending `{culture}` to all our pages.

Inside `Startup.cs`, we need to add the convention during razor config.

```cs
            services.AddRazorPages(options =>
            {
                options.Conventions.Add(new CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention());
            })
```

I created the `CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention.cs` under a `Middleware/` folder, but you can put it wherever (not sure if it's "technically" middleware?).

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace app.Middleware
{
    public class CultureTemplatePageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            // For each page Razor has detected
            foreach (var selector in model.Selectors)
            {
                // Grab the template string
                var template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template;

                // Skip the MicrosoftIdentity pages
                if (template.StartsWith("MicrosoftIdentity")) continue;

                // Prepend the /{culture?}/ route value to allow for route-based localization
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = AttributeRouteModel.CombineTemplates("{culture?}", template);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now going to `/en/home` should resolve, and `/home` should not.
But if you go to `/fr/home` you will notice that it's still using the English resx file. This is because the culture is not being updated based on the URL.

To fix this, more modifications to `Startup.cs` are necessary.

In the `Configure` method, we will add

```cs
            app.UseRequestLocalization();
```

Under `ConfigureServices`, we will configure the request localization options.
This will include adding a `RequestCultureProvider` which is used to determine the `Culture` for each request.

```cs
            services.Configure<RequestLocalizationOptions>(options =>
            {
                options.SetDefaultCulture("en");
                options.AddSupportedCultures("en", "fr");
                options.AddSupportedUICultures("en", "fr");
                options.FallBackToParentCultures = true;
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Remove(typeof(AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider));
                options.RequestCultureProviders.Insert(0, new Middleware.RouteDataRequestCultureProvider() { Options = options });
            });
```

This uses an extension method to remove the default accept-language header culture provider

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace app.Extensions
{
    public static class ListExtensions {
        public static void Remove<T>(this IList<T> list, Type type)
        {
            var items = list.Where(x => x.GetType() == type).ToList();
            items.ForEach(x => list.Remove(x));
        }
    }
}
```

More importantly, we need to create the `RouteDataRequestCultureProvider` we just added to the list.

`Middleware/RouteDataRequestCultureProvider.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace app.Middleware
{
    public class RouteDataRequestCultureProvider : RequestCultureProvider
    {
        public override Task<ProviderCultureResult> DetermineProviderCultureResult(HttpContext httpContext)
        {
            string routeCulture = (string)httpContext.Request.RouteValues["culture"];
            string urlCulture = httpContext.Request.Path.Value.Split('/')[1];

            // Culture provided in route values
            if (IsSupportedCulture(routeCulture))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(routeCulture));
            }
            // Culture provided in URL
            else if (IsSupportedCulture(urlCulture))
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(urlCulture));
            }
            else
            // Use default culture
            {
                return Task.FromResult(new ProviderCultureResult(DefaultCulture));
            }
        }

        /**
         * Culture must be in the list of supported cultures
         */
        private bool IsSupportedCulture(string lang) =>
            !string.IsNullOrEmpty(lang)
            && Options.SupportedCultures.Any(x =>
                x.TwoLetterISOLanguageName.Equals(
                    lang,
                    StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase
                )
            );

        private string DefaultCulture => Options.DefaultRequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
    }
}
```

Note we check for `RouteValues["culture"]` in this provider, when that value isn't actually present yet. This is because we need another piece of middleware for Blazor to work properly. But for now, at least our pages will have the correct culture applied from the URL, which will allow `/fr/` to use the correct `Index.fr.resx` instead of `Index.resx`.

Another issue is that the `asp-page` tag helper doesn't work unless you also specify `asp-route-culture` with the user's current culture. This sucks, so we will override the tag helper with one that just copies the culture every time.

Inside `_ViewImports.cshtml`

```
@* Override anchor tag helpers with our own to ensure URL culture is persisted *@
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@removeTagHelper Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers.AnchorTagHelper, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, app
```

and under `TagHelpders/CultureAnchorTagHelper.cs` we will add

```cs
using System;
using app.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;


// https://stackoverflow.com/a/59283426/11141271
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397920/razorpages-anchortaghelper-does-not-remove-index-from-href
// https://talagozis.com/en/asp-net-core/razor-pages-localisation-seo-friendly-urls
namespace app.TagHelpers
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ActionAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ControllerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = AreaAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = PageHandlerAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = FragmentAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = HostAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = ProtocolAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteAttributeName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesDictionaryName)]
    [HtmlTargetElement("a", Attributes = RouteValuesPrefix + "*")]
    public class CultureAnchorTagHelper : AnchorTagHelper
    {
        private const string ActionAttributeName = "asp-action";
        private const string ControllerAttributeName = "asp-controller";
        private const string AreaAttributeName = "asp-area";
        private const string PageAttributeName = "asp-page";
        private const string PageHandlerAttributeName = "asp-page-handler";
        private const string FragmentAttributeName = "asp-fragment";
        private const string HostAttributeName = "asp-host";
        private const string ProtocolAttributeName = "asp-protocol";
        private const string RouteAttributeName = "asp-route";
        private const string RouteValuesDictionaryName = "asp-all-route-data";
        private const string RouteValuesPrefix = "asp-route-";
        private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

        public CultureAnchorTagHelper(IHttpContextAccessor contextAccessor, IHtmlGenerator generator) :
            base(generator)
        {
            this._contextAccessor = contextAccessor;
        }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            var culture = _contextAccessor.HttpContext.Request.GetCulture();
            RouteValues["culture"] = culture;
            base.Process(context, output);
        }
    }
}
```

This uses an extension method to get the current culture from an `HttpRequest`

```cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace app.Extensions
{
    public static class HttpRequestExtensions
    {
        public static string GetCulture(this HttpRequest request)
        {
            return request.HttpContext.Features.Get<IRequestCultureFeature>()
            .RequestCulture.Culture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;
        }

    }
}
```

To make sure the dependency injection for the current context works, we need to modify `Startup.cs`

```cs
            // Used by the culture anchor tag helper
            services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

Now we can use the tag helper without things breaking.

Example:

```html
    <a asp-page="Page1">@Localizer["SomePage"]</a>
```

With normal pages working, now we can work on getting Blazor components translated.

Inside `_Imports.razor`, we will add

```
@using Microsoft.Extensions.Localization
```

Inside our `myComponent.razor`, we will add

```
@inject IStringLocalizer<myComponent> Localizer
```

Now we can use `<h1>@Localizer["Header"]</h1>` just like in our normal pages. But now there's another issue: our Blazor components aren't getting their Culture set correctly. The components see `/_blazor` as their URL instead of the page's URL. Comment out the `<base href="~/">` in your `<head>` element in `_Layout.cshtml` to make Blazor try hitting `/en/_blazor` instead of `/_blazor`. This will get a 404, but we will fix that.

Inside `Startup.cs`, we will register *another* middleware.

```cs
            app.Use(new BlazorCultureExtractor().Handle);
```

This call should be before the `app.UseEndpoints` and `app.UseRequestLocalization()` call.

`Middleware/BlazorCultureExtractor.cs`

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using app.Extensions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;

namespace app.Middleware
{
    public class BlazorCultureExtractor
    {
        private readonly Regex BlazorRequestPattern = new Regex("^/(.*?)(/_blazor.*)$");
        public async Task Handle(HttpContext context, Func<Task> next)
        {
            var match = BlazorRequestPattern.Match(context.Request.Path.Value);

            // If it's a request for a blazor endpoint
            if (match.Success)
            {
                // Grab the culture from the URL and store it in RouteValues
                // This allows IStringLocalizers to use the correct culture in Blazor components
                context.Request.RouteValues["culture"] = match.Groups[1].Value;
                // Remove the /culture/ from the URL so that Blazor works properly
                context.Request.Path = match.Groups[2].Value;
            }

            await next();
        }
    }
}
```

The middleware will check if the route is trying to hit `/en/_blazor`, will set the `RouteValues["culture"]` value to `en`, and will rewrite the path to `/_blazor` before further processing. This puts the lang in the route values for our `RequestCultureProvider` to use, while also fixing the 404 from blazor trying to hit our localized routes.

Inside `_Layout.cshtml` I also use

```
    <script src="~/_framework/blazor.server.js"></script>"
```

to ensure that the request for the blazor script hits the proper path instead of `/en/_framework/...`. Note the preceeding `~/` on the `src` attribute.

### Closing remarks

If you want pure URL-based localization instead of the weird cookie stuff MS promotes, then it's a lot of work.

I haven't bothered looking into doing this with Blazor **pages**, I'm just sticking with **components** for now.

e.g.,

```
<component>
    @(await Html.RenderComponentAsync<MyCounterComponent>(RenderMode.Server))
</component>
```

Comment: This is great answer. What would you provide for switching languages?

Comment: Redirecting the user to /fr/home should be enough, generating the link with non-current culture might be annoying since we override the default tag helper. In my app, there was some frontend framework JS that used a simple substitution on /en/ for /fr/ on the current window.location since I only supported those cultures

Comment: I feel that the amount of work to achieve this is ridiculous.  I did a variation for RouteDataRequestCultureProvider to return NullProviderCultureResult instead of default when there is no culture specified to give a chance to other providers to work (header etc). For language change I ended up doing <a asp-route-culture="en"></a> so it goes to the same page but translated.