# Blazor - localize page per request through route

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, localization, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I need to build a blazor-wasm project which has a bunch of widgets running.
Those widgets can than be added to any other page via an iframe.

Currently I am stuck how to enable localization for those widgets. I saw an article some weeks ago, but can find it anymore. As I remember it stated, that there are three options where to store the culture to be used by the page's localizer.

- Cookie
- Header
- QueryString/Route

What I want is to have the language/culture being part of the whole route as e.g. in the docs from Microsoft -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/lifecycle whereas the culture is the first part of the route.

I'm also pretty sure it was something that has to be defined in the application's startup. I searched together with blazor, razor, netcore, aspnet, aspnetcore but can find what I was looking for. It's not about localizing the server-part. Simply to have a page (widget) which culture is set through the route and directly known by the localizer (if the culture is supported)

Comment: Here is a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69562523/using-url-path-for-localization-in-razor-blazor-components) about localization by route in blazor, hope it can give you some help.